# source:convert command fails with error "The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object"

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx-cli, source

```
sfdx force:source:convert --sourcepath force-app  -d  deployment
ERROR running force:source:convert:  The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my CLI version information.

```
sfdx -v
sfdx-cli/7.49.1-2b6ba86a25 darwin-x64 node-v10.15.3
```

**OS**: MacOS 10.14.6

**Terminal**: zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0)

Comment: What shell are you using? That might have an effect.

Comment: @sfdcfox updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to locate the problem after going through the discussion in this issue: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/94

1. Created a new folder named `force-app1` and updated `force-app` in `sfdx-project.json` to `force-app1`
2. Copied entire `main` folder from `force-app` to `force-app1`
3. Tried the command `sfdx force:source:convert -p force-app1 -d test` and it failed.
4. Removed `force1-app/main/default/classes` folder and retried step 3, same result.
5. Repeated step 4 until I found which folder is causing the problem.

In my case, I had a file named `foo__c.field-meta.xml` in `installedPackages` folder. I have to trace my steps as why this happened but this is the root cause.

This error could be more specific than too generic and I hope this helps others.